# Umbrella term for online and offline

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on a web app. The app lists different events, which can be filtered by various criteria. Some events take place in a physical location and some of the events are online. The filter needs to allow the user to filter the events by online/offline. What is a good label for this? I don't want to use `type`, as it's too generic. The best I could come up with was `medium type`. I would appreciate better suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: event settings, location, event forum, venue type

Comment: event settings -> too broad, the event has a lot of other attributes as well
location -> the events, that happen at physical locations already have this filter;
venue type sounds nice though!

Comment: I fail to understand what's wrong with **location**. If it's physical (offline), the value could be an address or city; if it's online, the value could be *online*, a URL, or the name of a communication program.

Comment: @JasonBassford +1, wish it could be more.

Comment: @JasonBassford this does make sense, however there is additional metadata around events in the app that I'm working, which requires using a new field and not changing the functionality of any of the old fields (in this case `location`).

Comment: @Alexander You have to provide more details. What has already been used, and how, that precludes the use I have suggested?

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, I agree, that this requires more context. But venue type is a good suggestion, made by tblue. Thank you all very much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Online and offline work well but it sounds like you are referring to *Local* and *Remote*. Local would be the offline meaning they are not connected to or online with the internet.